# How does one go about creating custom IntelliJ project templates?

Tags: templates, intellij-idea, projects-and-solutions

I wish to have a custom project template in IntelliJ IDEA (Community edition 12.0)

What I need, is for the project, when created, to copy in some standard files and then insert some values into those files.

I can probably do this myself using a bit of bash magic, but it would be very nice and tidy to just pick the template when creating a new project and get it all done in one go..

MSVS has very good support for custom projects, and I was kind of hoping IntelliJ had some of the same, though I have not been able to find it.

The only thing I found was the plugin facility, but I couldn't get started with that - IntelliJ just tells me the package com.intellij.openapi.components doesn't exist when I add an application component to the plugin project.

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out that you can create project templates quite easily, all you do is go into the meny, tools, save project as template.
Unfortunately, this did not provide me with features I needed, so I have made a bash script to do what I need.

Comment: If it helps anybody, [here's a link to the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/saving-projects-as-templates.html) on how to save a project as a template, but the procedure is as Morten describes.